# Perl program to calculate neibouring residues from a pdb file

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

This is a program to extract the neighboring residues within 4.5 angstrom. I have resolved the program up to the atom numbers. From these I want to extract

- the residue numbers,
- residue name,
- atom № and
- atom name.

I would like to output this data in a tabular form so that I can directly copy the results. But now I'm stuck and require help to extract those fields for the atom numbers I obtained in `$close_atomno`, and also how to use the program for multiple pdb files and different catalytic residues in one go.

Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use List::Util qw(sum);
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use 5.010;

say "enter residue no.";
chomp(my $r_no = <STDIN>);

my (@all_pos, @all_data, @matching_pos, @matching_data);

my $residue_file = "neighbouring_residues.txt";
open my $out_fh1, '>', $residue_file or die "Can't open $residue_file: $!";

say "enter file name";
chomp(my $infile_name = <STDIN>);
open IN, '<', $infile_name or die "Can't open $infile_name: $!";

LINE: while (<IN>) {
   chomp; 
   /^ATOM/ or next LINE;
   my @fields = split;
   push @all_pos,  [ @fields[6 .. 8]    ];
   push @all_data, [ @fields[1 .. 3, 5] ];

   if( $fields[6] eq $r_no) { 
      say $_;
      push @matching_pos,  [ @fields[6 .. 8]    ];
      push @matching_data, [ @fields[1 .. 3, 5] ];
   } 
}

say $out_fh1 "Neighbouring residues at position $r_no in the 4.5A region are:";
my %close_atoms;

MATCHING_ATOM:
for my $i1 ( 0 .. $#matching_pos ) {
   my $matching_atom = $matching_data[$i1][1];
   $matching_atom eq $_ and next MATCHING_ATOM for qw/N CA O C/;
   for my $i2 ( 0 .. $#all_pos ) {
      my ($close_atomno, $close_residueno) = @{$all_data[$i2]}[0, 3];
      my $dist = distance($matching_pos[$i1], $all_pos[$i2]);
      if($dist < 4.5 and $close_residueno != $r_no) {
         $close_atoms{$close_atomno} = 1;
      }
   }
}

sub distance { sqrt sum map {$_**2} map {$_[0][$_] - $_[1][$_]} 0 .. $#{$_[0]} };

my @close_atoms = keys %close_atoms;

say $out_fh1 "@close_atoms";
for my $m (0 .. $#close_atoms) { 
   say $out_fh1 $all_pos[$m];# here is problem i want residue details according to $close_atomno 
}

say "result in $residue_file";
```

This would be a typical input file:

```
ATOM 9   N GLU A 1 35.540 1.925 27.662 1.00 19.70 N
ATOM 10 CA GLU A 1 35.626 1.018 28.802 1.00 20.96 C
ATOM 11  C GLU A 1 34.264 0.794 29.444 1.00 20.22 C
```

with columns in this order:

- atom
- atom number
- atom name
- residue name
- chain
- residue number
- x coord
- y coord
- z coord
- irrelevant
- irrelevant
- irrelevant

Comment: I know a lot about Perl, but nothing about `PDB` files. Could you provide a short test case (example input + expected output for that input) that makes it easier to understand what is going on, and what is going wrong?

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16355323/edit) your question to include the files

Comment: ATOM      9  N   GLU A   1      35.540   1.925  27.662  1.00 19.70           N  
ATOM     10  CA  GLU A   1      35.626   1.018  28.802  1.00 20.96           C  
ATOM     11  C   GLU A   1      34.264   0.794  29.444  1.00 20.22           C  
 
1st column is atom, 2nd is atom number, 3rd is atom name, 4th is residue name, 5th is chain 6th is residue no., 7,8,9 are coordinates to take dist, through the atom no i want to extract corresponding residue name,no. and atom name and no. column 10, 11 are not of use.

Comment: input is this data, through the coordinate we calculate distance between atoms and the atoms which are corresponding to the residue no given by user,if dist is less that 4.5 , print the atom, residue, and also to remove the redundant residue names.

Comment: I simplified your source code, by using logically equivalent transformations, removing unused variables, removing multiple calculation of the same data, and renaming a few variables. It will now compile with `use strict; use warnings;`, which you should always use. Now you could help by renaming some variables to something useful (`@pointsX` are not), and providing the expected output for the input example you gave—without a complete *test case* it is rather difficult to write working code to solve a complex problem.

Comment: firstly thank you very much for you time and effort. let me modify the ques, just tell me that for example i have a line like this: ATOM 2 c ser 45. now in an array i am having the values of 2nd column (2 in this case). with that  value i want to extract the corresponding values of column 3 and 4. so output will be SER 45. In the program the array points5 is having these numbers(column 2.)

Answer (score 1):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $base_r_no = $ARGV[0];
open IN, "<$ARGV[1]" or die;

my @atoms_data = map {[split]} grep {/^ATOM/} <IN>; 
foreach my $base_atom (grep {($$_[2] !~ /^N|CA|O|C$/) && ($$_[5] eq $base_r_no)} @atoms_data) {
    foreach my $matched_atom (grep {dist($base_atom,$_) < 4.5} @atoms_data) {
        print join("\t",@{$matched_atom})."\n";
    }
}

sub dist {
    return sqrt( ($$_[1][5]-$$_[0][5])**2 + ($$_[1][6]-$$_[0][6])**2 + ($$_[1][7]-$$_[0][7])**2 );
}
```

As for Multiple pdb files - I would just cat all the files into one file and hand it to the script.